# Force text onto new page

Tags: line-breaking

I have two tables and text. I would like to have the text start on a new page:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Decomposition Level 6}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
        \textbf{Channel} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{10} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fp1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{F3} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{C3} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{P3} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{O1} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & Ab & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{F7} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{T3} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{T5} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fc1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fc5} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cp1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cp5} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{F9} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & Ab & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fz} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cz} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Pz} & N & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & Ab & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{F4} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{C4} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{P4} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{O2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{F8} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{T4} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{T6} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & Ab & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fc2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fc6} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cp2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cp6} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{F10} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{EKG EKG} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{EKG 1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{EKG 2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & Ab & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{FP2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Decomposition Level 7}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
        \textbf{Channel} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{10} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fp1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{F3} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{C3} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{P3} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{O1} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & Ab & Ab & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{F7} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{T3} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & Ab & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{T5} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fc1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fc5} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cp1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cp5} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{F9} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & Ab & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fz} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cz} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Pz} & N & N & N & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{F4} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{C4} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{P4} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{O2} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & Ab & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{F8} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{T4} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{T6} & N & N & N & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fc2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fc6} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cp2} & N & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & Ab & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cp6} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{F10} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{EKG EKG} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{EKG 1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{EKG 2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & Ab & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{FP2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\newpage
From those two tables, it can be concluded that the seizure (mostly) happened at the 5th minute within the timeline. 
Previously it has been mentioned that the extracted recording was taken from 7:10-7:20AM data, so the 5th minute in the timeline refers to around 7:14-7:15AM. 
Finally, it can be concluded that it matched with the data provided in the text file \verb|Seizures-list-PN03.txt|.

\end{document}
```

When I run this code, the text will be written below the table. How can I force it to be be written in the following blank page? Seems the command `\newpage` doesn't work here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\clearpage` instead of `\newpage`. Here there is the solution.

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Decomposition Level 6}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
        \textbf{Channel} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{10} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fp1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{F3} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{C3} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{P3} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{O1} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & Ab & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{F7} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{T3} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{T5} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fc1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fc5} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cp1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cp5} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{F9} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & Ab & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fz} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cz} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Pz} & N & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & Ab & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{F4} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{C4} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{P4} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{O2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{F8} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{T4} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{T6} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & Ab & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fc2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fc6} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cp2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cp6} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{F10} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{EKG EKG} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{EKG 1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{EKG 2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & Ab & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{FP2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Decomposition Level 7}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
        \textbf{Channel} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{10} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fp1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{F3} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{C3} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{P3} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{O1} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & Ab & Ab & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{F7} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{T3} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & Ab & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{T5} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fc1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fc5} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cp1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cp5} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{F9} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & Ab & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fz} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cz} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Pz} & N & N & N & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{F4} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{C4} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{P4} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{O2} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & Ab & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{F8} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{T4} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{T6} & N & N & N & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fc2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Fc6} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cp2} & N & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & Ab & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{Cp6} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{F10} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{EKG EKG} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & Ab \\ \hline
        \textbf{EKG 1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{EKG 2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & Ab & N & N \\ \hline
        \textbf{FP2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\clearpage
From those two tables, it can be concluded that the seizure (mostly) happened at the 5th minute within the timeline. 
Previously it has been mentioned that the extracted recording was taken from 7:10-7:20AM data, so the 5th minute in the timeline refers to around 7:14-7:15AM. 
Finally, it can be concluded that it matched with the data provided in the text file \verb|Seizures-list-PN03.txt|.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your readers *won't* understand what “those tables” refers to.

Call them by reference and just leave them to float with the `[p]` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{table}[p]
\centering

\caption{Decomposition Level 6}
\label{tab:dl6}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{10}{c} @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Channel} & 
  \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} &
  \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8} &
  \textbf{9} & \textbf{10} \\
\midrule
\textbf{Fp1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{F3}  & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{C3}  & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{P3}  & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{O1}  & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & Ab & N & N \\
\textbf{F7}  & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{T3}  & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{T5}  & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{Fc1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{Fc5} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{Cp1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{Cp5} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{F9} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & Ab & N \\
\textbf{Fz} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{Cz} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{Pz} & N & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & Ab & N & N \\
\textbf{F4} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{C4} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{P4} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{O2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{F8} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{T4} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{T6} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & Ab & N & Ab \\
\textbf{Fc2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{Fc6} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{Cp2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & Ab \\
\textbf{Cp6} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{F10} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{EKG EKG} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{EKG 1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{EKG 2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & Ab & N & N \\
\textbf{FP2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}


\begin{table}[p]
\centering

\caption{Decomposition Level 7}
\label{tab:dl7}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{10}{c} @{}}
\toprule   
\textbf{Channel} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} &
  \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} &
  \textbf{8} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{10} \\
\textbf{Fp1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & Ab \\
\textbf{F3} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{C3} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & Ab \\
\textbf{P3} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{O1} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & Ab & Ab & N \\
\textbf{F7} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & Ab \\
\textbf{T3} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & Ab & N & N \\
\textbf{T5} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{Fc1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & Ab \\
\textbf{Fc5} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{Cp1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & Ab \\
\textbf{Cp5} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{F9} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & Ab & N \\
\textbf{Fz} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{Cz} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{Pz} & N & N & N & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N \\
\textbf{F4} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{C4} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{P4} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N & Ab \\
\textbf{O2} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & Ab & N & Ab \\
\textbf{F8} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{T4} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{T6} & N & N & N & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & Ab \\
\textbf{Fc2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{Fc6} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{Cp2} & N & N & N & N & N & Ab & N & Ab & N & N \\
\textbf{Cp6} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & Ab \\
\textbf{F10} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & Ab \\
\textbf{EKG EKG} & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & Ab \\
\textbf{EKG 1} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\
\textbf{EKG 2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & Ab & N & N \\
\textbf{FP2} & N & N & N & N & Ab & Ab & N & N & N & N \\
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

From tables~\ref{tab:dl6} and~\ref{tab:dl7} it can be concluded 
that the seizure (mostly) happened at the 5th minute within the 
timeline. Previously it has been mentioned that the extracted 
recording was taken from 7:10--7:20AM data, so the 5th minute in 
the timeline refers to around 7:14--7:15AM. Finally, it can be 
concluded that it matched with the data provided in the text 
file \texttt{Seizures-list-PN03.txt}.

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]